# Processing ForeignSecurityPrincipal

Tags: powershell, active-directory

`DomainA` and `DomainB` trust each other. Some `DomainB` users are members of `DomainA` local domain groups. How can I get `ForeignSecurityPrincipal` in PowerShell and get list of its groups?

Comment: Probably these groups are **universal** and not **domain local**? You can try running `Get-ADUser` against `ForeignSecurityPrincipals` folder and then query `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` against one of them.

Comment: These groups are surely domain local, but it's not the point. Get-ADUser won't fit because it's not a user, it's "just a placeholder for a user or group from trusted domain", as the description of FSP says

Comment: Hmm. You should connect to the DC in DomainB, get there a user and run `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` cmdlet against that user in domain A.

Comment: No again. Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership ** -Server DC_B shows group membership only in DomainB Groups.

Comment: How about `$user=get-aduser "DomainB\someuser" -server dc_b; get-adprincipalgroupmembership $user -server DC_A`?

Answer (score 5):

That was surprisingly simple:

```
    Get-ADObject -Filter {ObjectClass -eq "foreignSecurityPrincipal"} -Properties msds-principalname,memberof
```

where "msds-principalname" is sAMAccountName, so I can search now through FSPs by sAMAccountName and get its groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of foreign security principals in a domain by running `Get-ADObject` cmdlet with `SearchBase` set to `CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=domain,DC=com` and `LDAPFilter` to something acceptable, like `(|(objectCategory=user)(objectCategory=group))`. Then, you can use [this script](http://activelydirect.blogspot.ru/2011/01/dealing-with-foreignsecurityprincipal.html) to get its `domain\username`. Then you query that domain for DCs via `Get-ADDomain` and `Get-ADDomainController`, get the user object from there and run `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` in your current domain against the retrieved user. An example (untested, as I have no env with many domains):

```
$ldf='(|(objectCategory=user)(objectCategory=group))'
$fspc=(get-addomain).ForeignSecurityPrincipalsContainer
$fsps = get-adobject -ldapfilter $ldf -searchbase $fspc
# got principals here
foreach ($fsp in $fsps) {
    $fspsid=New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($fsp.cn)
    ($fspdomain, $fspsam) = ($securityPrincipalObject.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).value).Split("\")
    # ^ this can throw exceptions if there's no remote user, take care
    $fspdc=(get-addomaincontroller -domainname $fspdomain -discover)[0] # taking first one
    $fspuser=get-aduser $fspsam -server $fspdc.hostname # use crossdomain DNS to resolve the DC
    $fspgroups=get-adprincipalgroupmembership $fspuser # local query
    $fspgroups # now do whatever you need with them and the $fspuser
}
```